# Str.lower() is not the Lower Version of Itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, equality

For some reason when I try to make a string lowercase and check for equality with the 'is' operator, it returns false.

I have tried converting the strings to ascii tuples and found that they still have the exact same numbers, and are the exact same type, but they still fail the test.

```
'HELLO'.lower() is 'hello'  # False
'hello' is 'hello'  # True

'HELLO'.lower()  # 'hello'
x = 'HELLO'.lower()
x  # 'hello'
x is 'hello'  # False

tuple(map(lambda x: ord(x), 'hello'))  # (104, 101, 108, 108, 111)
tuple(map(lambda x: ord(x), 'HELLO'.lower()))  # (104, 101, 108, 108, 111)

tuple(map(lambda x: ord(x), 'hello')) is tuple(map(lambda x: ord(x), 'HELLO'.lower()))  # False
```

Should these strings not be equal?

Comment: `is` doesn't test equality.

Comment: I know it tests if the value and type are the same, but aren't they both identical in this case?

Comment: That's not what it tests at all.  What did you see when you looked up the `is` operator?

Comment: I thought that 'is' is a similar operator to '===' in javascript?

Comment: No, it tests for equality of *identity*.  [The documentation is your friend](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check that the values of two objects are the same, you should use the `==` operator instead.

The `is` operator verifies that two operands refer to the same object.

Some examples that better illustrate the differences between these two operators can be found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-operator-python/).

Answer (score 1):

The 2 objects `'HELLO'.lower()` and `'hello'` do not have the same string associated with them, `is` compares objects

'HELLO' is the string in the first object & you are appying the method `.lower()` to it. The second object's string is 'hello'. Hence the 2 objects are different

Try,

```
'HELLO'.lower() == 'hello'
```

This will compare the string from object 1 when converted to lower case & not the object itself.